# Does Gwent from Witcher 3 take inspiration from existing tabletop games?

Tags: recommendations

I'm new to card games but I really enjoy the minigame called Gwent in the Witcher 3 video game.

Are the mechanics of this game represented closely in any existing physical board or card games?

Comment: I haven't actually played Gwent, but I read up on it a bit, and it seems there are a few broad mechanics it's implementing:
1. Card collection
2. Deck building
3. Tableau building

Probably your best option would be to go to boardgamegeek.com and search for games by those tags, but a few come to mind: Magic: the gathering, Android: Netrunner, Dominion, 7 Wonders, Race for the Galaxy.

Comment: I think this is placed off topic unreasonably, if the reason for that is the reason given here. It's a fair question about a card game and if there is a game like it, that's not a recommendation imo.

Comment: @Wouter Asking "is there a game that meets this criteria" is exactly what a recommendation is.

Comment: Maybe Twilight Struggle, which also has the "draw X cards and play them all this turn, then draw more cards next turn" mechanic.